# What's the correct preposition for the verb "to mirror something."

Tags: prepositions

The context of this question: I am writing technical documentation in the field of computational science, i.e. simulating physical systems on the computer.

I am writing about a method, which takes in an existing mesh, creates the mirror image and joins the results. This way, if we have a symmetric problem, we need to create only half the geometry with our meshing tool, and we can then apply the mirroring operation.

What I want to know is the correct preposition for the following sentence:

*"Mirror the geometry by(?) the user-provided plane"*

Comment: Is the idea that a user provides a plane and the method mirrors its geometry?

Comment: Your question is actually nothing to do with the word ***mirror*** (which could just as well have been ***write about***, ***explain***, or whatever). It's just that you're talking about *the **geometry of** [something]* (or possibly talking about *doing something [by] **using** something else*, I dunno). *Answer the question **by / using / with / through** examples* - there's no fixed "correct" preposition.

Comment: @Juhasz correct. Thus, the method mirrors the geometry with the plane. What I want to express is that the plane is the mirror. If I would do the reverse, i.e. the cut a geometry using the plane, I would write "cut the geometry _with_ the plane"

Comment: The verb "mirror" doesn't require a preposition before the direct object as it is transitive (e.g., "The user-provided plane mirrored the existing mesh into an image...).  If you're changing into the passive voice such that the subject performing the mirroring becomes an indirect object, then the preposition "by" is always used for that no matter what the verb is (e.g., "The existing mesh was mirrored into an image by the user-provided plane.").

Comment: @BenjaminHarman The user-defined plane is passive in this sentence because it's an imaginary reference surface. I don't think it's supposed to be performing an action, so no action can be done *by* it.

Comment: reflecting or applying?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It has a lot to do with "mirror". OP is asking for preposition to use in an object of preposition phrase with complement "plane" that modifies the verb "mirror".

Comment: @mRotten: Okay, that's a *third* interpretation over and above the two I saw without caring much exactly how the text should be parsed. But it's a pretty complex relationship, nor naturally catered for by ordinary English preposition usage. And it's not obvious to me why many alternatives (including ***using, through, over*** shouldn't be equally "acceptable".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You could probably use the words you mention and a few other words/phrases including "with respect to". I didn't claim that your suggestions were incorrect. I only wanted to clarify that "by" is not ideal (hence the OPs request for a better word) because it's ambiguous. Case in point: Your interpretation of the OP's sentence using "by" (that the plane performs some action) is a completely reasonable one, but it's not the intended meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe a bit complex, but nothing English can't handle. As written, the statement is imperative, so the subject is you (understood). The verb is "mirror", the DO is "geometry", and the object of the preposition (addressing how the geometry is mirrored) is "plane". We just need the correct preposition to describe how the geometry is mirrored relative to the plane.

Comment: ***Of*** seems like the most obvious preposition. You *mirror the geometry **of** the plane*. But it's still an opinion-based question. (There is no *correct* answer.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Nope, you’re copying the geometry that exists on one side of the plane and pasting that geometry on the other side of the plane. You’re not copying the plane.

Comment: @JasonBassford This is not an opinion-based question. There are correct prepositions to use, and incorrect prepositions to use. “Of” is incorrect.

Comment: @mRotten Asking which preposition to use is almost always subjective. Although there might be cases where some are obviously wrong, it's very rare there are cases when only a single one will work. Where multiple will work, it's a matter of opinion which is *better*. Either that, or it's proofreading. I also disagree with why you think that ***of*** is wrong. ***From*** would also work. As would ***beside***. And ***outside***. You're making assumptions that may or may not be correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford Agreed that choosing the *best* preposition is almost always subjective. I can't say whether the OP described his use case correctly, but **of** is an incorrect answer to the problem he/she described. The plane is not being reflected, it is an imaginary plane of symmetry about which a mesh model (the "geometry") is reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I understand the operation: You have a function that reflects some mesh model ("geometry" in your sentence). To do this, you need the user to provide a plane for the reflection operation (the "user-provided plane"). Every point on the model is then duplicated on the other side of the plane at a location defined by 1) the inverse of the normal component of the original point and 2) the parallel component of the original point (both relative to the user-defined plane).

In this context, you're asking for a preposition to use to describe *how* the original mesh model is mirrored with respect to the plane.

If I have that right, use one of:

> Mirror the geometry **about** the user-provided plane
>
> Mirror the geometry **across** the user-provided plane

You might also consider using **reflect** instead of **mirror**, since the former more often has an object of a preposition. I'm not sure if using **reflect** would make this sentence more clear to your reader, but that replacement makes it more clear that **about** and **across** are better choices as the preposition for "user-provided plane".

Comment: +1 for *reflect*